# How to pass clone of object instance to another widget to prevent changes reflect back Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to pass an object instance to a custom dialog widget where I make modifications in the parameters of that instance. There is a save button which is clicked if we want to save those changes and see the result of final changes back in the main widget.

The issue I am facing right now is that if I make changes in object instance and don't click save button and close the dialog window, the object instance changes.

I have tried to pass the copy of that object but it didn't work at all.

This is my code snippet:

```html
Future modifierDialog() {
    return showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      barrierLabel: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).modalBarrierDismissLabel,
      barrierColor: Colors.black45,
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext, Animation animation,
          Animation secondaryAnimation) {
        return Dialog(
          child: ModifiersDialogWidget(
            menuItem: item.copyWith(),
            setSelection: (selectedItem, extras) {
              //widget.addToCart(item);
              HotKeysWidget.of(context)!.editCartItem(selectedItem, extras);
            },
            editItem: true,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

```html
class ModifiersDialogWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Food menuItem;
  final Function(Food, List<Map<String, dynamic>>)
      setSelection; /////to save changes + add to cart
  final bool editItem; ///////null if it is not edit cart item

  const ModifiersDialogWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.menuItem,
    required this.setSelection,
    required this.editItem,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return ModifiersDialogWidgetState();
  }
}
```

Save callback to save change is as below:

```html
RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.green,
            onPressed:
                requiredFilledModifiers.length == widget.data!['totalRequired']
                    ? () {
                        if (errorTxt.isNotEmpty) {
                          setState(() {
                            errorTxt = '';
                          });
                        }

                        widget.setSelection(menuItem, extraItems);
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      }
                    : null,
            child: const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 15),
              child: Text(
                'Done',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

This is my object class:

```html
class Food {
  String id;
  String name;
  double price; 

  Food copyWith() => Food(
        id,
        name,
        price,
        );

  Food(
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.price,
  );
}
```

Can anyone help me with this issue, please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dart works as pass-by-value for objects itself but their nested structures (for example class fields) appear to be pointers

```
class A {
  int count = 1;
}

void changeField(A instance) {
  instance.count = 3;
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  var a = A();
  changeField(a);
  //prints 3
  print(a.count);
}
```

So if you want to copy your whole class without affecting its field change - you need to create a new instance of that class. You may achieve it creating an interface with `copy` method that will produce new instance of itself:

```
    mixin ICopyableMixin<T>{
      T get copy;
   }
```

Updating the code:

```
    class A with ICopyableMixin<A> {
      int count = 1;
     
      @override
      A get copy => A();
    }
    
    void changeField(A instance) {
      //calling copy here
      instance.copy.count = 3;
    }
    
    void main(List<String> args) {
      var a = A();
      changeField(a);
      //prints 1 because changeField copies instance of the original
      print(a.count);
    }
```

Comment: I am using the same concept as yours. If you look into my code above I am passing the  copy of that instance.

Comment: But it alters the original instance as well.

Comment: So provide source of your `item.copyWith()` then

Comment: Updated my post. Have a look please.

Comment: Also attache a snippet of code where the save button is pressed ( onTap or onPressed callbacks )

Comment: It would be great if you attach snippet of code where those actions actually happen. It is hard to understand cause of the problem now

Comment: I would definitely share that code snippet but there is a whole bunch of code which is not possible to share. That's why I have shared only the code snippet of ```StatefulWidget``` named ```ModifiersDialogWidget ```.